# ASP.NET MVC view - alternative frameworks

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I know there exist alternative frameworks for creating views, different from the standard way of creating views in ASP.NET MVC. What alternative do you suggest and why?

Answer (score 2):

Here my list....

- [NVelocity](http://nvelocity.sourceforge.net/)
  Some examples here...
  [Alternate View Engines with ASP.NET MVC (NVelocity)](http://www.chadmyers.com/Blog/archive/2007/11/28/testing-scottgu-alternate-view-engines-with-asp.net-mvc-nvelocity.aspx)
- [NHAML View engine](http://code.google.com/p/nhaml/downloads/list)
  [Introducing NHAML](http://andrewpeters.net/2007/12/19/introducing-nhaml-an-aspnet-mvc-view-engine/)

I liked NHAML because of

- Less noise more content
- Never forget a closing tag
- Identifiers and Selectors, Css-Friendly
- Server Side Code/Tokens Syntax

More details at

[Introduction to NHAML and ASP.NET MVC](http://andrewpeters.net/2007/12/19/introducing-nhaml-an-aspnet-mvc-view-engine/)  (This one contains useful information).

and

[ASP.NET and NHAML](http://devlicio.us/blogs/sergio_pereira/archive/2008/10/29/asp-net-mvc-and-nhaml.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative ASP.NET MVC framework is the (open source) [Vici MVC framework](http://viciproject.com/mvc).